# Is there no way to ask Metal to give us vertexes per instances?

Tags: metal, metalkit

Is there any way to ask Metal to give us vertexes per instances ?

I am drawing bezier lines. for that i want to change the number of vertexes for each bezier lines

Any way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to change the number of vertices per instance in Metal (or any other API AFAIK).

The main benefit of instancing is that is allows you to draw many instances of the same mesh with a single draw call.  This lowers the CPU overhead and the size of the command buffer.   However, it's not for drawing many different meshes with a single draw call.

Instead, you can use  a new feature in Metal which will be available in iOS 12 and macOS 10.14 to add many draw calls (each with a different number of vertices) to an [*indirect command buffer*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/fundamental_lessons/basic_indirect_command_buffers?language=objc).  Executing this buffer requires only single call, so it has the same performance benefits as instancing but is more flexible.

If you're targeting earlier OSes, you can build a series *MTLDrawPrimitivesIndirectArguments* into a Metal buffer and call `-[MTLRenderCommandEncoder drawPrimitives:indirectBuffer:indirectBufferOffset:]` for each.  This will add a draw call per object so it's not as fast as instancing or indirect command buffers, but it allows you to do some interesting things (like build a list of draw calls on the GPU with a compute kernel)